Google OAuth consent: Is ownership confirmation by URL not enough?
I have a valid Google ID and for Google Analytics, I have activated a property with this ID, say app.mydomain.com.
So I can fully use Google Analytics for app.mydomain.com. I verified the ownership for this property by URL.
Next I tried to create an OAuth consent loginscreen for app.mydomain.com. During verification for production state, Google says:

Issues Found Your home page website is not registered to you. Verify
ownership of your home page.

My Questions:

Does this mean that URL ownership verification is not enough, it must be domain ownership?
Does this mean that something different is missing in the configuration of Analytics / Search Console and Could API Services?
What next step makes sense?


Did you manage to find any relevant information for this?

@DiegoFortes See my answer.

The answer is too long for a comment. Thanks @Diego Fortes for asking.
I learnt that if you have an OAuth consent screen, Google requires to confirm the ownership of the main domain. But my Google Analytics property has been confirmed for a subdomain.
It may sound silly, but it took me a while to see that.
So you cannot create something like https://myapp.the-company.com, getting consent for this, and then make an OAuth consent loginscreen for myapp.the-company.com. You must configure the consent loginsreen for the-company.com, and this will not be granted by the property for myapp.the-company.com.
As a second part, I would like to add that on the Cloud Console, you have organisations, projects, service users and users. It is important that these identieies match with the identities on the Search Console. Make sure that the ownership is the same by checking all the organisation details that are unveiled.
